# how can I select specific cells after filtering

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a specific range after filtering.

```
Sub macros()
Dim newrange As Range, rw As Range
Set newrange = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
Dim a As String
a = InputBox("Number")
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$V$121").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=a

Sheets("ABV 3").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$V$126").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=a

Sheets("ABV 3 FFF").Select
Range("H6:S6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("ABV 3").Select
Range("H6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

In the filter, I set a number and I need to select the range from H to S. How can I do this????

Comment: ima nooby in vba

Comment: `Range("H6, S6")`  did you mean `Range("H6:S6")` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes, I meant `Range("H6:S6")`

Comment: If you're just starting in VBA then this will be useful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba   Following the guidelines there will save you plenty of problems.

Comment: What is not happening that you expect? What happens when you try to record yourself doing what you intend? It would also help if you could post what you EXPECT to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: @PGSystemTester, I have a runtime error 1004, how can i fix this?

Comment: @TimWilliams, this is necessary for work where you need to iterate over 1000 rows

Comment: What is necessary?